# Formula Help - Multiplying using Number and Text fields

Tags: formula, number, text

I need to alter this formula to include a text field (The text field displays a number)

```
IF((ISPICKVAL(Louvre_Calculator__c, "215mm Louvre Calculator")),
(Pivot_mm__c - 4)-(**2*60**), 
(Pivot_mm__c - 4)
)
```

I want to change the 2*60 with the output of field infill_profile_size__c.  Infill_profile_size__c is a formula field that spits out either 40 or 60 but is displaying as a text field and is causing the IF statement to error.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `VALUE(infill_profile_size__c)` to convert TEXT to NUMBER

```
IF((ISPICKVAL(Louvre_Calculator__c, "215mm Louvre Calculator")),
(Pivot_mm__c - 4)-(2*VALUE(infill_profile_size__c)), 
(Pivot_mm__c - 4)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the VALUE function to convert text to a number:

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Louvre_Calculator__c, "215mm Louvre Calculator"),
  (Pivot_mm__c - 4)-(2*VALUE(infill_profile_size__c)), 
  (Pivot_mm__c - 4))
```

Coincidentally, you can make this formula a bit smaller:

```
(Pivot_mm__c - 4)-(2*
  IF(ISPICKVAL(Louvre_Calculator__c, "215mm Louvre Calculator"),
  VALUE(infill_profile_size__c), 0))
```